# Calculate input impedance of transmission line without knowing L or C

Tags: ac, impedance, transmission-line, characteristic-impedance

I have the following problem:

> A TV antenna lead-in wire 10 cm long has a characteristic impedance of 250 ohms and is open-circuited at its end. If the line operates at 400 MHz, determine its input impedance.

I know the following formula for input impedance \$Z_{in}\$:

\begin{equation}
Z_{in} = \frac{Z_0}{j\tan(\beta L)}
\end{equation}

where \$\beta\$ is the [phase constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Phase_constant), \$L\$ the length of the line, \$Z_0\$ the characteristic impedance an \$j=\sqrt{-1}\$. The question is, how do I find beta? The only formulas I can find for beta involve both the capacitance and inductance per length of the transmission line, neither of which are given in the problem.

Comment: You are correct. The problem can't be solved with the given information. You need to know the velocity factor of the line, which you could get from the L and C values if you had them.

Comment: Maybe you can answer the question if you make a reasonable assumption. With that impedance it is probably twinlead wire. You might just look up the L and C of 300 Ohm twinlead (which is very common) and tweak the L and C slightly to get 250 Ohms instead. Then use that L and C.

Comment: That sounds like it would be a reasonable estimate for the real world, but unfortunately, this is a textbook problem, so I don't know if I can do that.

Comment: It is usually better to make assumptions, state them up front, then answer using those assumptions than not to answer at all. You could also assume it is ladder line so that effectively, beta = beta of free space. Just make sure you document your assumptions.

Comment: I agree with @mkeith If the question doesn't provide any other detail its a fair assumption to just use free space, therefore phase constant = 3.3356e-9 * 2 * pi * f